# Trick to solve $(I_n+ae_{ik})(I_n+b e_{kj})(I_n- a e_{ik})(I_n-b e_{kj})$ without massive expressions.

Tags: linear-algebra

For $i \ne j$ we define the following matrix: $E_{ij}(\lambda)=(I_n+\lambda e_{ij})$

I want to show that for pairwise different $i,j,k$ and any $a,b$ the following holds:
$$E_{ij}(ab) = E_{ik}(a)E_{kj}(b)E_{ik}(a)^{-1}E_{kj}(b)^{-1}$$
which is equivalent to solving $$(I_n+ae_{ik})(I_n+b e_{kj})(I_n- a e_{ik})(I_n-b e_{kj})$$
Is there a way to solve this expression without massive expressions from distributing the identities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define, $e_{ij}$ to be the $n \times n$ matrix having $ij$-th entry 1 and all others 0. Try to find out the products of several forms of those matrices. 
You can refer to the problem 6 of chapter 7.2 (pg 238-239) of Abstract algebra by Dummit and Foote.

Comment: Yes, I see the pattern. However, I don't see how this rule translates to this case, as the matrix has $1$ on the diagonal.

Comment: Yeah you can write $E_{ij}(\lambda)$ as $I+ \lambda e_{ij}$ and expand.

Comment: One more way is that: if you already learnt the effect of adding scalar multiple of one row with another (elementary row operation) and the equivalence of it in terms of matrix multiplication, you can certainly use that technique.

Comment: I believe you when you say it can be solved this way. :) My issue is that if I distribute/expand without doing anything else, I get an insanely long expression. I don't have anything clever to make it shorter, do you have any tips?

Comment: One short cut way is to learn and solve once for the elementary matrices $e_{ij}$ as I mentioned in my answer and then use those relations as I said in my comment.

Comment: Otherwise, you may think is as effects of elementary row operations on Identity matrix and calculate it without necessarily going to any calculations.

Comment: How do I get to multiplying elementary matrices before expanding? The elementary matrices are in the parentheses with the identity matrices. I know their values too.

Comment: Only you have to check that let's say, elementary row operation adding $j$-th row multiplied with $\lambda$ to $i$-th row of a $n \times n$ matrix $A$  is left multiplication by $E_{ij}(\lambda)$ to the matrix $A$.

Comment: Can you conclude from my previous comment what will be the effect of multiplying $E_{ij}(\lambda)^-1$ to the left of $A$? using idea of row operations.

Comment: I can conclude what the effect will be when multiplying with $e_{ij}$, but I can't say the same for $E$.

Comment: Did you prove the statement I stated  regarding row operation and Multiplying with E to the left?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to understand why if $i$, $j$, $k$ are three distinct variables (as in programming languages), the unique substitution $j \leftarrow j + abi$ has the same effect as the following list of substitutions:

$k \leftarrow k + a i$
$j \leftarrow j + b k$
$k \leftarrow k - ai$
$j \leftarrow j - bk$

We see that the variable $k$ will indeed not be changed by this list of substitutions, the third one cancelling the first one. The variable $j$ will have after the second step the initial value of $j + bk + bai$. And the final step removes the $bk$.

But this explanation is the same thing as expanding the expression you gave, except it is more informal. When you expand $(I + a e_{ik})(I + b e_{kj})$, you get the matrix describing the values after the second step in terms of the initial values. When you multiply on the right this matrix by $(I-ae_{ik})$, you get the description of the values of the variables at the third step. Etc. I wouldn't call this a massive expression though.

Comment: Why are you multiplying the indices and scalars?

Comment: @RubenKruepper These are not indices actually, these are variables as in a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that all your matrices act as the identity on all basis vectors except those labelled $i,j,k$; so we need only compute what happens to these three vectors. It is also clear that all the matrices send these three vectors to linear combinations of these three. So we can restrict ourselves to the case $n=3$, and without loss of generality we may assume $i=1$, $j=3$ and $k=2$.

Then
$$
E_{12}(a)E_{23}(b)=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 &1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & b\\
0 & 0 &1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & ab\\
0 & 1 & b\\
0 & 0 &1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence
$$
E_{12}(a)^{-1}E_{23}^{-1}(b)=
E_{12}(-a)E_{23}(-b)=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -a & ab\\
0 & 1 & -b\\
0 & 0 &1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Finally
$$
[E_{12}(a),E_{23}(b)]=
E_{12}(a)E_{23}(b)E_{12}(a)^{-1}E_{23}^{-1}(b)=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & ab\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 &1
\end{bmatrix}=
E_{13}(ab).
$$